# Sybase ASE 15 + Hibernate: SybSQLException when using quotes in queries

Tags: sql, hibernate, syntax-error, sap-ase

I'm getting syntax error for Hibernate 3.3.2 generated queries containing double-quotes:

```
create table tbl_version (
    id int identity not null,
    "code_name" varchar(255) null,
    version_nbr varchar(255) null,
    software_name varchar(255) null,
    primary key (id)
)

Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone knows what's the problem?
Since I have the right dialect, I guess Sybase needs some config change.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this error with hibernate, but in Transact-SQL you should call set quoted_identifier on go before table ddl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue for the JDBC4 driver:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-4661

As a workaround, you can append  the following to the JDBC URL: `?SQLINITSTRING=set quoted_identifier on`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use bracketed quoted identifiers like

```
create table tbl_version (
    id int identity not null,
    [code_name] varchar(255) null,
    version_nbr varchar(255) null,
    software_name varchar(255) null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

this works with Sybase versions from 12.5.1 (compatible with Microsoft SQL Server)